# Doesn't still AKS support vertical pod autoscaling?

Tags: azure-aks

I didn't found documentation about VPA in Azure in the official documentation site, is it supported by Azure AKS?

Comment: As of today, AKS nodes only scale horizontally.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.